# Edit Text property of JButton and of Every control has become disabled

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-8

I am using 
netbean 8.1,
java 8,
window 7 64 bit.
I am facing a problem that The  Text property of every control has become disabled in one InternalFrame.
[image]

Can any one tell me why?
In my previous Internalframe the EditText property is working.
and If I created new InternalFrame then also the property is enabled properly.
What may be the problem in my InternalFrame?

Comment: This question is not about Swing. It's about the Visual Designer of Netbeans.

Comment: no I dont think...Something wrong in my code, or in that internalframe property because when I create new Jinternal frame and create any control then edittext property of that control is enabled.